# Pass multiple custom variables to other jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Trying to effectively pass multiple custom variables (about 10 of them) to other pipeline jobs through dotenv, by not creating 10x "- echo Var=Var". The custom variables have different values depending if the Environment is Dev,Test,Prod etc (about 8 different environments) as well.

From my understanding I can use child jobs to differentiate between environments, and use extends functionality as a config file to create all the variables for the different environments. Problem is that it's very cumbersome logic to use the bellow code when I’m going to add all the variables for all the environments.

Example code:

```
#Seperate file
.environment:Test:
  variables:
    CustomVar_ExtendServerFQDN: 'TestHost'
    CustomVar_Datacenter: 'TestDatacenter'  

.environment:Dev:
  variables:
    CustomVar_ExtendServerFQDN: 'DevHost'
    CustomVar_Datacenter: 'DevDatacenter' 

#Prep file
EnvironmentPrep:Dev:
  stage: build
  extends: .environment:Dev
  script:
    - echo "ServerFQDN=$CustomVar_ServerFQDN" >> build.env
    - echo "Datacenter=$CustomVar_Datacenter" >> build.env
    - echo "GitLab CI/CD | Print all environment variables"
    - env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
  rules:
  - if: '$Environment=="Dev"'

EnvironmentPrep:Test:
  stage: build
  extends: .environment:Test
  script: 
    - echo "ServerFQDN=$CustomVar_ServerFQDN" >> build.env
    - echo "Datacenter=$CustomVar_Datacenter" >> build.env
    - echo "GitLab CI/CD | Print all environment variables"
    - env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
  rules:
   - if: '$Environment=="Test"'

#Main job file
MainJob:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Main Environment variable is [$Environment] [$Server]"
    - echo "GitLab CI/CD | Print all environment variables"
    - env

variables:
  Environment: 'Test'
```

With this logic it means 10x "-echo var=$var", in each environment job, total of 80 "-echo var=$var" for the merged YAML.

Is there a more effective logic to make sure the MainJob gets the custom variables retrieved from a build stage job?

I'm looking for something like the bellow example, but I'm not sure how to create the logic or filter on only the custom variables "CustomVar_*" for variable $scriptBlock:

```
#Seperate file
.environment:Test:
  variables:
    CustomVar_ExtendServerFQDN: 'TestHost'
    CustomVar_Datacenter: 'TestDatacenter'  

.environment:Dev:
  variables:
    CustomVar_ExtendServerFQDN: 'DevHost'
    CustomVar_Datacenter: 'DevDatacenter' 

EnvironmentPrep:Dev:
  stage: build
  extends: .environment:Dev
  script:
    - $scriptBlock >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
  rules:
  - if: '$Environment=="Dev"'

EnvironmentPrep:Test:
  stage: build
  extends: .environment:Test
  script: 
    - $scriptBlock >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
  rules:
   - if: '$Environment=="Test"'

MainJob:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Main Environment variable is [$Environment] [$Server]"
    - echo "GitLab CI/CD | Print all environment variables"
    - env

variables:
  Environment: 'Test'
  scriptBlock: <SOME FILTER LOGIC ON "CustomVar_*">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put only the environment specific information in one job for each environment and the rest in an "extends", as follows:

```
.EnvironmentPrep:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "ServerFQDN=$Env_ServerFQDN" >> build.env
    - echo "Datacenter=$Env_Datacenter" >> build.env
    - echo "GitLab CI/CD | Print all environment variables"
    - env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

EnvironmentPrep:Dev:
  extends: .EnvironmentPrep
  rules:
    - if: $Environment=="Dev"
  variables:
    Env_ExtendServerFQDN: 'TestHost'
    Env_Datacenter: 'TestDatacenter'

EnvironmentPrep:Test:
  extends: .EnvironmentPrep
  rules:
    - if: $Environment=="Test"
  variables:
    Env_ExtendServerFQDN: 'DevHost'
    Env_Datacenter: 'DevDatacenter'
```